# Print statement not executing while using in cursor in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am using SQL Server 2012: This is the query using cursors.

```
create table test(id varchar(10), name varchar(10))

insert into test values('1','a'),('2','b'),('3','c')

declare @id varchar(10)
declare @name varchar(10)

declare cur cursor for 
    select id, name  
    from test

open cur 

if @@CURSOR_ROWS > 0
begin 
    fetch next from cur into @id, @name

    while @@FETCH_STATUS=0
    begin
        print 'test'
        print @id+','+@name

        fetch next from cur into @id,@name
    end
end

close cur
deallocate cur
```

But in the result set it doesn't display results, but gets successfully executed.

Expected result

```
1,a
2,b
3,c
```

Comment: you don't need to check @@CURSOR_ROWS!

Comment: [`@@CURSOR_ROWS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176044.aspx) - it returns `-1` for dynamic cursors.

Comment: If you **really must** use cursors (if ever possible **avoid cursors!**), then you should know what **options** to use to get the least performance drawbacks - [see Aaron Bertrand's blog post on the topic](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/09/t-sql-queries/cursor-options) - read and learn from the master!

Answer (score 2):

`@@CURSOR_ROWS` is returning `-1` that's why it's not printing.

Try this:

```
declare @id     varchar(10)
declare @name   varchar(10)

declare  cur cursor for 
    select id, name from test

open cur    
fetch next from cur into @id, @name

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
    print @id+','+@name

    fetch next from cur into @id,@name
end

close cur
deallocate cur
```

Read more about [@@CURSOR_ROWS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176044.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).